# Non-uniform pixel distribution; two resolutions in one file in GIMP

Tags: gimp, resolution

Is there a way to achieve with GIMP to have two resolutions in one file? Say that I want a small area (filled rectangle below) inside a less sharp file. By this I mean, if I zoom really into the maroon part of the file below, I hardly start seeing pixels while if I do so on the white part I do.

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you should use a layout program instead of an image editor. A PDF can contain images at different resolutions.

Comment: If you mean different images with different PPI settings, then no that isn't possible in GIMP.  It is possible in other software however, such as Inkscape (a vector image editor which can import raster images) or page layout software such as Scribus. However, it is possible to scale smaller images in GIMP using interpolation set to none. That will preserve blocky pixels.

Comment: Ok thanks to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is artificially pixellize the big image while keeping the smaller image intact. For instance, in the image below, the cat image has been pixellized 3x3 (`Filters > Blur > Pixellize`) so when you zoom in you see "pixels" in the cat before you see them in the text.

[image]

Comment: Or place a small low res image and scale it up using interpolation: none.

Comment: @BillyKerr Indeed...

Comment: From OP's image it seems that they believe this method will prevent huge files. Perhaps you should clarify that this isn't a method to decrease file size.

Comment: @Wolff actually it will. The "big pixels" will compress better. The cats head alone is 2.2MB as a PNG, and down to 1.8 if pixelized 2x2 and 1.2MB if pixelized 3x3. For JPEG, a slight Gaussian blur provides equivalent results.

Comment: OK, point taken. I just meant that this is an aesthetic effect. Not something graphic designers normally do to decrease file size. Compression is supposed to take care of that.

Comment: yes, but you also decrease the quality of the text... (but on the whole in 2024 disk size and bandwidth make this a non-problem).